# C# match and export based on listbox textfile and wildcard

Tags: c#

I like to thank stackoverflow member AlbertEin for helping with this code.  What I have is a file being created from a massive directory listing, and i also have a listbox full of items that are only part of the file name in the directory listing.  What I want to do is write out a text file for every listboxitem in listbox1.item based on the item and a wildcard

Example Listbox:
Apple
Orange

Results Apple.txt:
Apple13.txt
Apple15.txt
Apple19.txt

and just do this foreach item in the listbox.  I'd also like to only read the master txt file once to save me from reading it everytime.  Any help appricated.

Better explaination:

I have a listbox of 100 items, and 1 master text file that was created.

For all items in the listbox that match the master test file, I want to write out the matching contents of the master text file to a new textfile with the listboxs name.

The listbox items needs a wildcard in order to match the master text file.

Comment: I think that you're not being clear enough, i don't understand what exactly you want to do, besides, you're welcome ;)

Comment: What's most important, speed (I would imagine), resource usage, elegance of code?

Comment: You want to create one file from every listbox item containing the big file entries that match some expression?

Comment: Could you describe the requirements from the wildcard?

Comment: it would just be apple* would pull anything after apple

Yes AlbertEin to your 2nd comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, i don't know what kind of wildcard do you want to use, so i'm only checking that the line starts like the listbox item:

```
//Popullate listItems from your ListBox     
var listItems = new string[] { "Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple" };
var writers = new StreamWriter[listItems.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
{
    writers[i] = File.CreateText(listItems[i] + ".txt");
}
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(bigFatFile));

string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listItems.Length; i++)
    {
        if (line.StartsWith(listItems[i]))
            writers[i].WriteLine(line);
    }
}
reader.Close();
foreach (var writer in writers)
    writer.Close();
```

Comment: i'm confused on your varlistitem = new string [],  do i just want the {listbox1.item} here?  The listbox is being populated from a text file that can contain anything

Comment: listItems must be a string array with the elements of your listbox, just popullate it with the ListBox items

Comment: var listItems = new string[] {listBox1.items};  doesnt compile maybe i am missing what you mean

Comment: var listItems = new string[] {listBox1.Items.ToString()}; ?

Comment: var listItems = listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

Comment: hey i'm having (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations. issues on the other thread you helped on AlbertEin, any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: I fixed the STA, but what do I do to add the wildcard here?  I'd assume the if (line.Startswith(listItems[i})) would do it, but it doesnt input anything into the corrisponding text file

Comment: If the wildcard is always at the end you need to do if (line.StartsWith(listItems[i].Substring(0, listItems[i].Length - 1))

Comment: And also, this spits out all the files to my desktop, how can i get the files to go to my destionation directory

Comment: Jeez, think about it a little, change the line:
    writers[i] = File.CreateText(listItems[i] + ".txt");
to include the path that you want to use. like

    writers[i] = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(somePath, listItems[i] + ".txt"));

Comment: Maybe i'm not saying what i mean by wildcard because it's creating the test files fine, but it's not filling in any of the contents.  What I mean by wild card is apple* will fill in apple12.txt apple14.txt in the apple.txt file

Comment: bah. its on my end i'm running to much stuff
ignore my riduclous requests and thanks Albert!